# Data modeling - Vehicles in Salesforce

Tags: data, asset

We are starting to think about how we want to model vehicles in Salesforce. We currently have service cloud and a new requirement arised around being able to track driver vehicles. The requirements are pretty basic, make, model, cubic capacity and model year.

There is an asset object that may be used but thinking this may be overkill for our very basic use case and wondering whether a custom object makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this object to use:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_location.htm

As it states:

> Represents a warehouse, service vehicle, work site, or other element of the region where your team performs field service work.

Might be that there is some customization left to do, but by default you would also have the possibility to use some kind of parent location, where your vehicle could be placed. (thinking of a car sharing use case here)